# Eloquent relations between three (or four?) models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I would appreciate an input on how to properly approach the problem with relations, since I am a bit lost. I do not want to use raw queries (I would have solved this problem in no time with those), I want to use eloquent since I am still learning it.

I have three models (at the moment): `Job`, `JobReview` and `Review`.

- `Job` has many `JobReview`
- `JobReview` belongs to `Job`
- `JobReview` has many `Review`
- `Review` belongs to many `JobReview` (?)

To explain. I have a table with `Job` where N jobs can be created (not limited). Each `Job` can have only one `JobReview`, while each `JobReview` can have N `Review`. `Review` are basically a pre-set questions that need to be answered when rating a completed job.

I have already tried a few combinations with belongsToMany, hasMany, hasOne, but none of those are giving back results I want.

On top of all that, `JobReview` also needs to store two additional fields when saving `Review` response: `rating` and `content`. First is a number between 1-5 and second is text content.

Am I missing a fourth model here, something like:

- `Job` has one `JobReview`
- `JobReview` belongs to `Job`
- `JobReview` has many `JobReviewAnswer`
- `JobReviewAnswer` belongs to `JobReview`
- `JobReviewAnswer` has one `Review`
- `Review` has many `JobReviewAnswer`

Answer (score 0):

[Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) is what you are looking for.

`Review` has many `JobReview` and `JobReview` has many `Review`.

You will also have to work this out with a pivot table, so read the docs carefully.

I cannot fully understand your business logic, so I cannot really give a specific answer on how to do it. I don't know what your `Review` is since you already got `JobReview`.